# Is there a way to read my god's abilities before the game starts?

Tags: smite

I'm still pretty new to Smite, and I like playing Assault to get random new gods and give them a try. However, I always find myself "idling" in base for a minute after spawn to read all the new god's abilities, and usually miss some of the nuance to them because I'm trying to get the basics fast so that I can help my team.

Is there any way I can start reading while still in the god select screen, to save time once the actual game starts? I can see how to choose skins and voice packs and stuff, but I can't tell if there's a way to view your currently selected god's abilities.

Comment: I'm pretty certain there isn't a detailed view on the god selection screen. I haven't played in a couple months so that might've changed (why I'm not answering). What I would do when given a new god is turn on autoskill and sometimes autobuy. When the match starts let the team know I haven't used the god before, then press 'K' to open up the detail view and do a bit of research. Most of the time I'm able to get a basic understanding of everything before the match actually gets going. I'll snoop around when I get the chance to see if it changed.

Comment: @Rapitor Yeah, I thought I remembered seeing it when I last played (a year ago?), but I couldn't find it anymore. I've been using 'K' to read skills but there's a ton of info on that screen and I'd like any extra time I can get to read up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is.

[image: God Selection Screen Screenshot]

On the left-hand side where all the selected gods are visible, you can click on any of the selected god's portrait, which will bring up a window for details about that particular god. One of the tabs on the window is called "ABILITIES" and should list all of the abilities for the god in pretty good detail. Simply mouse over the individual abilities to read what they do.

[image: Ability Overview Screenshot]

Answer (score -3):

Strix, you can view them before you even start a match just go to 
Gods> Click on a god> 
there will be several tabs on the left hand side such as stats and abilities 
Hope you find what your looking for :)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm particularly interested in how to view abilities after my god is randomly chosen but before the match starts. I don't want to study every single god before joining an Assault game.